# When does ILDASM/ILASM cause a change in the PDB

Tags: c#, clr, cil, pdb-files

I want to know what kind of changes does one have to do to make the PDB for a given dll invalid.

I'm guessing adding MSIL code to methods is definitely going to change. But is metadata going to also change a PDB? For example if I add a new typeref or something like that?

Comment: How do you define invalid? You could change the timestamp or the hash so that the debugger can't find it any more. But if you still load the PDB, e.g. with `.symopt +40`, it will be loaded and valid.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood. You want to leave the PDB as is and modify the DLL by changing the IL code contained in it. Doesn't the DLL have a checksum that would make the DLL invalid?